# The type string is expected but a type integer was received with value 0

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I am working on Marketing APIs. I want to hit this Api to get Estimate of Target Audiences, basically how much users will be able to see my ad.

```
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{adaccountid}/reachestimate"
```

I am getting the response until I pass this parameter "flexible_spec". Whenever I pass this parameter I get this response "The type string is expected but a type integer was received with value 0". I searched for it but no solution was there.

I will show you what I tried until now:

```
 1)"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2//{adaccountid}/reachestimate?     targeting_spec={"geo_locations":{"countries":   ["IN"]},"flexible_spec":{"interests":["6006289279425"]}}
 2) "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2//{adaccountid}/reachestimate?     targeting_spec={"geo_locations":{"countries":   ["IN"]},"flexible_spec":{"interests":["Movies"]}} 
 3)"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2//{adaccountid}/reachestimate?     targeting_spec={"geo_locations":{"countries":   ["IN"]},"flexible_spec":{"interests":["id":"6006289279425","name":"Movies"]}}
```

I have tried sending an array of ids in flexible spec interests  , array of name's in flexible_spec interests and I have also tried sending `list<interests>` in it. But no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched alot about this error. Then i came to know about my mistake i am doing in this API. We can specify interests fields in two types:

```
 1) targeting_spec={"geo_locations":{"countries":"IN"]},"flexible_spec":[{"interests":["6006289279425"]}]}
 2) targeting_spec={"geo_locations":{"countries":   ["IN"]},"interests":["6006289279425","46345343534"]}
```

first one passing interests array in flexible_spec array.
second one passing interests as an array object but not in flexible_spec.

This helped me . I am posting this answer because it might help you too in the same situation.
Thanks.